# Is this really a resource leak

Tags: java, nio

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
FileChannel fileChannel = fos.getChannel();
FileWriter fileWriter = Channels.newWriter( fileChannel, Charset.forName("UTF-8").newEncoder(), -1 );
....
fileWriter.close()
```

I'm getting a compiler warning that since 'fos' isn't closed, I have a resource leak.  I'm assuming, but have thus far failed to prove, that when I call 'fileWriter.close()', the resource is cleaned up.

Comment: why not try with resources? then you won't need to worry about closing them :)

Comment: Stuck deploying in java 6 and java 5 environments sometimes... thus...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not a resource leak but the compiler isn't smart enough to figure that out.

When you close your `FileWriter`, it closes the `FileChannel`, which in turn closes the `FileOutputStream`.

This of course, may not be the case with different JVM's. I've only looked at the code in the Oracle's Java8 `rt.jar`.

Since it's not stated as part of the public contract of `FileWriter`, it's a good idea to explicitly close all streams you create.